# How to send strings to GWT DataGrid?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I have the method that carry out the data from the table. How could I pass these records to the  datagrid of the google web toolkit?

```
public void getAllGitRecords(){
    try {
        db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(dbAdres);
        db.open("admin", "admin");
        try {
            for (ODocument gitCommitsTable : db.browseClass("GitStorage")) {
                //May be I should put the data in some container here? 
                //So what kind of container it could be?
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.getRecord().getIdentity() + " | ");  
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("sha") + " | "); 
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("comment") + " | "); 
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("date") + " | "); 
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("h") + " | ");
                System.out.print(gitCommitsTable.field("m") + " | ");
                System.out.println(gitCommitsTable.field("l") + " | ");
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println("The table GitStorage is empty");
        }
    } finally {
        db.close(); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is this server or client code ?

Comment: Then you also have to transfer the data to the client first. For example via a RCP ( http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html )  .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read a tutorial on Cell widgets in GWT:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html